# Tricky situation involving conversion functions?

Tags: c++, class, object, data-conversion

I have run into this situation I find really tricky. I have 2 classes: time12 and time24 which maintain time on a 12 hr and 24 hr basis respectively. Both of them are supposed to have individual conversion functions to handle conversions to the other type. But if I declare time 12 first, then the "time24" in the prototype of the conversion function will be undefined as the time24 class will be declared later. So what do I do now? I can't even only declare it inside and define it after the 2nd class. So now what?

```
class time12
{
 operator time24()  //time24 is undefined at this stage
 {

 }
};

class time24
{

};
```

Comment: And what language are you working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in c++ you have 2 types of files, .h and .cpp. Your .h file is your declaration, and .cpp is your definition.

Example:

convtime.h:

```
#ifndef CONVTIME_H_ //this is to prevent repeated definition of convtime.h
#define CONVTIME_H_

class time24; //for the operator in class12

class time12
{
public:
    time12(int); //constructor
    operator time24();
private:
    //list your private functions and members here
}

class time24
{
public:
    time24(int); //constructor
private:
    //list your private functions and members here
}

#endif //CONVTIME_H_
```

convtime.cpp:

```
#include "convtime.h"

//constructor for time12
time12::time12(int n)
{
    //your code
}

//operator() overload definition for time12
time24 time12::operator()
{
    //your code
}

//constructor for time24
time24::time24(int n)
{
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the class without defining it in C++:

```
class time24;

class time12
{
 operator time24()  //time24 is undefined at this stage
 {

 }
};

class time24
{

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a language - 
if you are dealing with a dynamic typed language, such as Python, ther eis no such problem -
the other type only need to be known at execution time, when the conversion method is called - not at parse (compile) time - so the following code is valid:

```
class Time12(Time):
   def toTime24(self):
       return Time24(self._value)

class Time24(Time):
   def toTime12(self):
       return Time12(self._value)
```

By the time the "toTime24" method is called, the global name "Time24" is defined to be the proper class.

In C++ - you can declare a class stub that works much the same as  function prototype - just do:

```
class time24;

class time12
{ ... }

class time24
{ ... }
```

Not shure how this works in other statically typed languages.

Comment: Ok - just saw now you had put the language at the top of the question, not as a tag - anyway, I will keep this answer as an example of how things work in the dynamic typing world.

Comment: Proomoted the answer to wiki, so people from other static languages (java, c#), can add how it is done there